# Should I Accept This Consulting Internship Offer?

Tags: internship, consulting

I was recently offered a consulting internship at a management consulting firm. They're not MBB but also not a boutique firm (they have around 1,000 employees worldwide). However, after the interview today, I got to know more about the project that I will be assigned on. The client that I'll be working with is a lumber insurance company. The culture and vibe of the company itself is honestly really great; the people were nice and super friendly. I'll definitely be learning a lot through this opportunity. However, I don't know how to feel about the client since I'm quite passionate about sustainability in general. However, I am a current college sophomore who plans to do consulting in the future and I don't think I'll get a better offer this summer. Also, I really want to be able to learn more about consulting but im kinda conflicted I guess.

Comment: What is the matter with lumber insurance? Many places forestry is a managed sustainable resource. Perhaps you should give a locale.

Comment: What does a lumber insurance company have to do with sustainability? They provide a financial instrument, nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

> However, I don't know how to feel about the client since I'm quite passionate about sustainability in general

You should truly set aside your present vague - however admirable - quasi-political emotions, and **grab the amazing opportunity**.

One important factor: if you must look at it that way, it's critical to ***know the enemy***.

Your current notions of "sustainability, etc" are generalities: you will become incredibly informed by working hard on such a project. Enjoy!